# sendkeys doesn't work on input field

Tags: java, selenium

I'm having a strange problem. sendkeys doesn't work on an input field although I am able to do a click on it.

I also tried setAttribute and even that doesn't work.

The input field is constantly monitoring user input and triggers a javascript when the user enters x number of characters. Is this causing the problem?

I tried these:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id']")).sendKeys(c‌odeStr); 
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('id').value='‌ 
123456'"); 
((JavascriptExecutor) 
driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('id').
setAttr‌ibute('value', '123456')");
```

This is the error I receive: 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //input[@id='id']

but the click works fine:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id']")).click();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Please add your code to troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried these: 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id']")).sendKeys(codeStr); 

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('id').value='123456'");

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('value', '123456')");

Comment: This is the error I receive:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //input[@id='id']

but the click works fine:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id']")).click();

Comment: have you tried first clicking the element, then entering the text?

Comment: Yes click works fine but sendkeys doesn't work

Comment: Rather than the `value` attribute, try modifying the `value` property of the DOM.

Can you also provide us with an HTML snippet?

Comment: Could you please give me a sample for modifying the value property of the DOM?
Here is the HTML code
<span class="InputLabel_base__1w4B2 placeholder-mode">id</span>
<input id=“id” autocomplete="off" name="verificationCode" class=“class_text” value="" type="tel">